# How to sort a table using javascript without using dependencies?

Tags: javascript, sorting

I'm trying to sort a HTML table using javascript. But I am not sure where to start. I need to sort the table when the user clicks on the header. The sorted content should replace the original content in the table.

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>School Name</td>
    <td>Phone number</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>23423424</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>xyz</td>
    <td>567653424</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>def</td>
    <td>095423424</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Things you need to learn in order to be able to do this: How to bind an event handler. How to search for DOM elements. How to sort an array. How to insert elements into the document. Maybe that helps to get started.

Comment: Or just search for "sort table javascript"

Comment: ^ https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+sort+table

Comment: https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html